# php: Get then post large files and memory

Tags: php, file, memory

I'm building a script which transfers large files (1G) from a point A with a GET request to point B with a POST request. 
I built it with NodeJs (pipe stream) but I want to do it with php. 
I was wondering how php works with files. Is it loading all the file into the memory? or is it possible to pipe a stream into a request?

Point A -----GET---> PHP script -----POST-----> Point B

Speaking of memory, is the `memory_limit` per script execution? Or is for all parallel scripts? Because there are multiple transfers at the same time.

Comment: [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). Be sure to read the [Common Pitfalls](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) section. You should consider using a reputable library for uploading files. It is rather easy to make mistakes, if you do not know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I think this is possible however you would have to change the values in the PHP.ini for max upload size and max post size

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @d-jones, It is a backend process, there is no POST request to the server but POST from the server.

Comment: Then forgive me kindly